# Yearly Archive from a custom date metabox (Event Start Date)

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, wp-get-archives

I have created a custom post_type called (event) and here's the code

```
            // Register Custom Post Type Events
        function custom_post_type_events() {

            $labels = array(
                'name'                => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
                'singular_name'       => _x( 'Event', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'Events', 'text_domain' ),
                'parent_item_colon'   => __( '', 'text_domain' ),
                'all_items'           => __( 'All Events', 'text_domain' ),
                'view_item'           => __( 'View Event', 'text_domain' ),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Event', 'text_domain' ),
                'add_new'             => __( 'New Event', 'text_domain' ),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Event', 'text_domain' ),
                'update_item'         => __( 'Update Event', 'text_domain' ),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Search events', 'text_domain' ),
                'not_found'           => __( 'No events found', 'text_domain' ),
                'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No events found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
            );
            $args = array(
                'label'               => __( 'event', 'text_domain' ),
                'description'         => __( 'Events information pages', 'text_domain' ),
                'labels'              => $labels,
                'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats', ),
                'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
                'hierarchical'        => false,
                'public'              => true,
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'show_in_menu'        => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
                'menu_position'       => 5,
                'menu_icon' => admin_url() . '/images/ef-events-icon.png',  // Icon Path
                'can_export'          => true,
                'has_archive'         => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => true,
                'publicly_queryable'  => true,
                'capability_type'     => 'page',
            );
            register_post_type( 'event', $args );

        }

        // Hook into the 'init' action
        add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_events', 0 );
```

Then I have created a custom date meta_box for this event post_type, and here's the code

```
                add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'dt_person_meta_boxes' );
            function dt_person_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
                $meta_boxes[] = array(
                    'id' => 'dt_metabox',
                    'title' => 'Event Date and Time',
                    'pages' => array('event'),
                    'context' => 'side',
                    'priority' => 'high',
                    'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
                    'fields' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'Event Start Date',
                            'desc' => 'Pick the date of this event',
                            'id' => $prefix . 'event_starttextdate',
                            'type' => 'text_date'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'Event End Date',
                            'desc' => 'Pick the date of this event',
                            'id' => $prefix . 'event_endtextdate',
                            'type' => 'text_date'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'Event Time',
                            'desc' => 'Enter event time (eg. 05:00 p.m.)',
                            'id' => $prefix . 'event_time',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'save' => true
                        )
                    )
                );  
                return $meta_boxes;
            }
```

---

My question is:

How to build a custom archive page for the custom post_type (event), that will sort events by the custom meta-box (event_starttextdate) ???

Example:

**2013**

- Event-1
- Event-2

**2012**

- Event-3
- Event-4

**2011**

- Event-5
- Event-6
- Event-7
- Event-8

---

Your help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I am trying to get the archives' monthly links from the custom date metabox I have created, but when I try to get this by typing (wp_get_archives('type=monthly')), it gives me the monthly links from the default WordPress publish date not from the custom date metabox, that is it ... ?? And I did not try anything yet because I do not know how to get it.

Comment: No response!!!!!

Comment: I have a life outside of WPSE ;) Have you run across the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) yet?  It explicitly allows for creation of archive pages for CPTs; in your case, you could create a file named `archive-event.php`.

Comment: Hello Pat J, I think you did not get what I need until now, thank you for your help but I think you are far away about what I need. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

**I just coded a workaround solution for this issue, if anyone is interested here is my solution:**

- This solution is using the [Bootstrap Navs Option](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs) , so you need first to download Bootstrap and link it in your header or index file.
- Please read the comments in the below code carefully to can understanding what is happened

**The Solution (Code):**

```
                <?php

            /*
            Template Name: Archives Events
            */
            echo '<div class="tabbable">';/* Start Bootstrap Tabs Parent Div (tabbable) */

            $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'event',/* Change with your custom post type name */
              'meta_key' => 'event_starttextdate',/* Change with your custom date metabox (Event Start Date) */
              'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
              'order'       => 'ASC',

            );

            /* Important Variables */
            $emptyvalue = "";
            $optionname = "optionname";
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

            /* Start Bootstrap Tabs ul */
            echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';

            /* Query Posts (Events) */
            $arr = array();
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->next_post();
            $id= $the_query->post->ID;

            /* Get all dates of posts from the custom date metabox (Event Start Date)  */
            $evestdate = get_post_meta($id, 'event_starttextdate', true);
            /* Strtime the year from the results  */
            $this_month = strtotime($evestdate);
            $cuseveyear = date( 'Y', $this_month );
            $archiveyear = $cuseveyear;
            $archiveyears = $archiveyear;

            /* Remove duplicated years */
            if(!in_array($archiveyear, $arr)){
            array_push($arr, $archiveyear);
            $get_archiveyear = $_GET['institution-archiveyear'];

            /* For each year do the following  */
            foreach( (array) $archiveyears as $archiveyear ) {
                echo '<li>';/* create li and a href for each year  */
                echo "<a class='archiveyear' href='#".$archiveyear."' data-toggle='tab'>";  /* href is equal to the result year  */
                echo $archiveyear ;
                echo '</a>'; 
                echo '</li>';

                }
            }

            endwhile;
            echo '</ul>';
            /* End Bootstrap Tabs ul */
            ?>

            <?php

            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'event',/* Change with your custom post type name */
            'meta_key' => 'event_starttextdate',/* Change with your custom date metabox (Event Start Date) */
            'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            );

            /* Important Variables */
            $emptyvalue = "";
            $optionname = "optionname";
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

            /* Start Bootstrap Tab content div */
            echo '<div class="tab-content">';
            $arr = array();

            /* Query Posts (Events) */
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->next_post();
            $id= $the_query->post->ID;

            /* Get all dates of posts from the custom date metabox (Event Start Date)  */
            $evestdate = get_post_meta($id, 'event_starttextdate', true);
            /* Strtime the year from the results  */
            $this_month = strtotime($evestdate);
            $cuseveyear = date( 'Y', $this_month );
            $archiveyear = $cuseveyear;
            $archiveyears = $archiveyear;

            /* Remove duplicated years */
            if(!in_array($archiveyear, $arr)){
            array_push($arr, $archiveyear);
            $get_archiveyear = $_GET['institution-archiveyear'];

            /* For each year do the following  */
            foreach( (array) $archiveyears as $archiveyear ) {
            /* create Bootstrap div tab-pane */
            echo "<div class='tab-pane' id='".$archiveyear."'>";
            $argss = array(
            'post_type'=> 'event',
            );              

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $argss );
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

            /* Get all dates of posts from the custom date metabox (Event Start Date)  */
            $evestdate_single = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event_starttextdate', true );

            /* Strtime the year from the results  */
            $this_month_single = strtotime($evestdate_single);
            $cuseveyear_single = date( 'Y', $this_month_single );
            $cuspermalink = get_post_permalink($id);


            /* If the result year is equal to the archive year do the following  */
            if ($cuseveyear_single == $archiveyear) {

            echo '<p style="border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;padding:0;padding-bottom:5px;margin-left:100px;">';
            echo "<a href='".$cuspermalink."'>";
            echo the_title();
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</p>';
            }

            endwhile;
            } echo '</div>';/* End Bootstrap div tab-pane */
            }

            endwhile;
            echo '</div>';/* End Bootstrap Tab content div */
            echo '</div>';/* End Bootstrap Tabs Parent Div (tabbable) */

            ?>
```